# Jquery: Hide Radio button with count

Tags: jquery

How to hide radio button, when it works when count is specified in jquery.
I've four radio buttons designed on html page.

```
           <div id="option">
            <input type="radio" id="one" value=1>
            <input type="radio" id="two" value=2>
            <input type="radio" id="three" value=3>
            <input type="radio" id="four" value=4>
            </div>
```

If count of radio button is 2, display the first two radio options.
If count of radio button is 4, display all the four options.

```
var numberOfCheckedRadio = $('input:radio').length;

$(document).ready(function () {
    if ( numberOfCheckedRadio = 2 ) {
       
        $('#one').show();
        $('#two').show();
       }
    else {
        $('#one').show();
        $('#two').show();
        $('#three').show();
        $('#four').show();
      }
    });
```

Comment: `if ( numberOfCheckedRadio = 2 ) {` should probably use `==`. Furthermore you lack an accolade to close your if statement

Comment: You get the number of radio inputs. Then check if it are 2 and show the first two, otherwise you show 1-4. That basically translates to "always show the exisiting radio inputs 1-4" Thats highly redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
var numberOfCheckedRadio = $("input[type='radio']").length;

$(document).ready(function () {
  //hide them all
    $("input[type='radio']").hide();

    if ( numberOfCheckedRadio === 2 ) {
       
        $('#one').show();
        $('#two').show();
    }
    else if(numberOfCheckedRadio === 4) {
        $('#one').show();
        $('#two').show();
        $('#three').show();
        $('#four').show();
      }
   else{
        //do some thing you want with other condition
    }

});
```

Comment: Should there be a closing brace of elseif

Comment: you can copy from this :) https://playcode.io/670901/ I code play.io

Comment: The values are hiding, but the buttons remain same as 4

Comment: you change number of radio button you will see the result change. You talk if 4 will show all input

Comment: Not working. I could see the buttons still. Can you make it work on playcode.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are showing 1 and 2 always, don't even put them into an `if` clause:

```
$(function () {
    // Just show
    $('#one').show();
    $('#two').show();
    // If there are more than 2 radio buttons
    if ( $('input[type="radio"]').length > 2 ) {
        // Show those
        $('#three').show();
        $('#four').show();
    }
});
```

As @Lapskaus points out though, you should be able to just show them all no matter what because if your logic depends on their full count being displayed then you shouldn't need to hide any of the radio buttons because it sounds like your PHP is going to determine the count in the first place and remove or add them first. If you have a total of 4 but only want to show 2, then that is a different story, then you want some logic, but here, either way, you want the max to show based on what is rendered to the page. I would just not hide them in the first place.

If they are being hidden by JS before this point in your script and you need JS to reveal them, then just do:

```
$(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').show();
});
```